# Delphi - Listview+OwnerData = beep on Keypress

Tags: delphi, listview, virtual

With a TListView using OwnerData (virtual), when I press a key with the LV as activecontrol, it makes a BEEP sound. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Remy Lebeau said, the problem is `OnDataFind` was not implemented, but you should  implement it like that:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewDataFind(Sender: TObject; Find: TItemFind; const FindString: string;
  const FindPosition: TPoint; FindData: Pointer; StartIndex: Integer; Direction: TSearchDirection;
  Wrap: Boolean; var Index: Integer);
begin
  // Here we must find currently selected element
  if Assigned((Sender as TListView).Selected) then
    Index := (Sender as TListView).Selected.Index;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the beep. Is it ok to ask for something else here related to this, or shall I accept now and make a new question? (how to retrieve the item index of the found data). I'm not sure if FindData actually works here, as it triggers with any key (I call FindCaption on KeyPress)

Answer (score 2):

The control is likely trying to perform a search of the list data to find an item thatmatches the text you are typing.  Did you implemented the `OnDataFind` event?

Comment: I have now, but the beep still occurs. Also, Index seems to be always -1 after FindData triggers? (even if it does find something).